# How to lookup Spotify User metadata (playlists, currently playing, etc)

Tags: spotify

I only see Artist, Album, and Tracks lookups in the docs. I want to display what I'm currently listening to. Is there a way to do this using the API?

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotify does not provide this at this time.  You can either get it by turning on last.fm scrobbling or accessing facebook music data.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Unfortunately there's no easy way to link back to the Spotify track after doing this short of searching and hopefully getting a match. Hopefully Spotify open up this API soon!

Comment: Facebook's data does include the link to the spotify track.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fmusic.listens

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas said Spotify does not provide such a feature 'directly'.
But there are some ways to get it work.

You have to me some more sprcific what you want to do. Web/Desktop/App
I wrote a tiny console app using an external dll

"File/Link removed" - send pm for further information!

If this is what you need just message me. It's a rly tiny application just for test purposes! Because I currently develop a overlay.

Comment: Eh, I don't need it that badly. I just wanted to know if it was available in the official API. Would love to see the source of how your app works though?

Comment: I can send you source of course.
send me mail info@tom-oliver.eu
@rakm